# Herkunft: Der Würfel brennt

Tags: etymology

Wenn beim Brettspiel der Würfel auf der Kippe steht und es zwei mögliche Augenzahlen als Möglichkeit gibt, gibt es den Ausdruck: "Brand!", oder "Der [Würfel] brennt!".

Woher kommt dieser Ausdruck? Der Duden erwähnt diese Bedeutung nicht unter Brand und in diversen Internetforen findet man nur Spekulationen ohne Beleg.

Comment: Den Ausdruck habe ich noch nie gehört

Comment: Wir hatten ihn heute Abend am Spieltisch in Hessen. Kenne es aber auch von meinen norddeutschen Verwandeten, für den Fall, dass es was regionales ist.

Comment: In Berlin ist der Ausdruck sehr gebräuchlich.

Comment: Vermutung: Es steckt bestimmt nichts weltbewegendes dahinter. Ist schätzungsweise nur ein actionreiches Synonym für "ungewöhnliche Situation".

Comment: In Niedersachsen ist mir der Ausdruck "Der [Würfel] brennt" durchaus bekannt.

Comment: Hm, auch nur Spekulation, aber könnte es über 'brenzlig' entstanden sein?  Der 'brennende' Würfel steht, wie jede brenzlige Situation, äußerst instabil, schlecht interpretierbar und mit ungewissem Ausgang.

Comment: Kenne ich auch aus Österreich, gibt es also auch im Süden.

Comment: In Rheinhessen sagt man (oder: meine Familie) dazu *angebrannt*.

Comment: Man sagt gelegentlich im Sport "der Ball ist noch heiß", wenn er nicht deutlich im Aus liegt, also noch gespielt werden darf, bzw. noch mal gespielt werden muss. Dies sagt man aber auch, wenn das Spiel besonders gut läuft, als wäre die Temperatur des Balls dafür verantwortlich. 

Woher diese Metapher eigentlich stammt, etwa dem heißen Eisen des Schmiedes, oder volkstümlichen Vorstellungen über die Belebtheit des Feuers, das weiß ich wirklich nicht. Zwar ist *heiß* nicht gleich *brennend*.

Comment: Der Ausdruck ist überregional bekannt. Vgl. https://berlin-backgammon.org/turnierregeln/ , http://www.suedbaden-cup.de/turnierregeln.html , https://www.reddit.com/r/DoesNotTranslate/comments/4csvuw/german_auf_kippe_the_state_of_a_die_that_doesnt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zunächst einmal sei gesagt, dass der Ausdruck recht alt zu sein scheint und es Belege für mindestens [Anfang](https://books.google.de/books?id=2VVeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&source=bl&ots=65tqCrFSoh&sig=ACfU3U3zQBf_4RC40MOG05f4FcF-YIFfhg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz-Y3EhePlAhWJwsQBHYoaD644ChDoATADegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&f=false) und [spätestens Mitte](https://books.google.de/books?id=yL5DAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP574&lpg=PP574&dq=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&source=bl&ots=VzscZo7vhy&sig=ACfU3U1X7MOQqlwG2NzwdoVSwVW-v94i1w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz-Y3EhePlAhWJwsQBHYoaD644ChDoATAFegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&f=false) des 19. Jahrhunderts gibt.

In "[Das neue königliche l'hombre, nebst einer gründlichen Anweisung wie [...] zu spielen sind](https://books.google.de/books?id=2VVeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&source=bl&ots=65tqCrFSoh&sig=ACfU3U3zQBf_4RC40MOG05f4FcF-YIFfhg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz-Y3EhePlAhWJwsQBHYoaD644ChDoATADegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&f=false)" von 1808 steht:

> Die Würfel, welche auf die Leisten springen, und die, welche nicht recht gerade stehen, sich brennen, wenn sie gleich in dem Brettspiele bleiben, gelten nicht.

In "[Volkskundliche Quellen](https://books.google.de/books?id=iw5mCPon118C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&source=bl&ots=PdC-jWNFZL&sig=ACfU3U3iq-xu_vQQ6tYB2keM5iBPrQ5bCw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz-Y3EhePlAhWJwsQBHYoaD644ChDoATAEegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=w%C3%BCrfel%20schr%C3%A4g%20brennen&f=false)" von 1912 steht zum Eintrag brennen

> ... Wir lassen noch ein Paar eigenthümliche Anwendungen unsres Wortes folgen. Es liegt hier im Allgemeinen die Warnung zu Grunde, einem Gegenstande, gleichwie einen Feuer, nicht zu nahe zu kommen. So, wenn im Blindekuhspiel derjenige, dem die Augen verbunden sind, einer Wand, einem Schranke zu nahe kommt, so ruft man ihm warnen zu: es brennt. - Wenn beim Würfeln ein Würfel sich an etwas stößt, daß er schräg zu liegen kommt, so heißt es: es brennt und der Wurf gilt nicht.

Dazu sei gesagt, dass im Spiel [Zehntausend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zehntausend_(Spiel)) die Möglichkeit besteht einen Würfel durch Schlagen auf den Tisch (Klopfen) in eine nicht-schräge Position zu bringen. Dies wird auch als Löschen bezeichnet. Wie alt dieses Spiel ist, bzw. ob es Vorgänger gibt, konnte ich nicht prüfen.

Die Zitate geben allerdings 2 Interpretationen her:

**1) Ein Würfel der brennt ist "verbrannt" und zählt nicht für den Wurf.**

**2) Ein brennender Würfel darf nicht angefasst werden und dadurch in eine eindeutige Position gebracht werden.**

---

Unwahrscheinlich, aber der Vollständigkeit haber gibt es noch den [Eintrag 2b) für brennen im Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB11198#XGB11198)

> 2) reflexives brennen
>
> b) sich irren

Der Würfel könnte sich also auch "irren". Aber wie gesagt ist dies für mich die unwahrscheinlichste Interpretation.

Comment: Mit der letzten Aussage haben sie sich wohl *geschnitten*, um nicht zu sagen, *sie sind wohl irre* :) Die Reflexivität sieht mir eher altertümlich aus, in beiden Fällen. Das finde ich doch besser als es aus *brenzlig* abzuleiten. Also doch eher anders herum? Vielleicht wie Würfel: gut durchgeschüttelt. Jedenfalls würde ich versuchen, von dem Bezug zu Feuer wegzukommen. hinsichtlich *irre* vergleich verwandtes *aberrant* "abwegig", quasi "weglaufend".

Comment: @vectory warum sollte man von dem Bezug zu Feuer wegkommen wollen, wenn es keine (wirklichen) gegenteiligen Belege gibt?

Comment: warum sollte man gegenteilige Belege suchen wenn man schon an einer modernen wortwörtlichen Interpretation festhält? Von *verbrannt* steht dort nirgendwo etwas, von nicht anfassen ebensowenig. Als ich mit Bezug auf *heiß* antwortete, wurde das ausgeschlagen. Man kann es euch einfach nicht recht machen.

Answer (score 0):

> Hm, auch nur Spekulation, aber könnte es über 'brenzlig' entstanden sein? Der 'brennende' Würfel steht, wie jede brenzlige Situation, äußerst instabil, schlecht interpretierbar und mit ungewissem Ausgang. – Hitch-22 Apr 29 at 12:15

Der Vermutung möchte ich eine weitere Hinzufügen: Vgl. Fränkisch, AHD, Mittelalterlatein *Brand* "Schwert"; Liest man das als "Klinge", bzw. Eng. *edge* (eher "Kante, Ecke", im Gegensatz zu Eng. *blade* "Klinge, [Rasier-]Blatt) und vergleicht "auf Messers schneide", kann man einen Zusammenhang zu des Spielbretts Kante erahnen, auf welcher der Würfel schief liegt.

Vgl auch *haarscharf*, *knapp* (vgl *knife*, *Knipse*, etc). Das finde ich überzeugend.

Comment: ich sage übrigens ganz anders "Der Würfel steht kippe".

Comment: Vergleich eventuel auch Germanisch *frama*, eine Waffe (ich denke Spieße), unbekannter Herkunft, zu weilen zu Eng *frame* "Rahmen" verglichen; Zusammenhang zwischen *frame* und *Rahmen* ebenfalls unsicher. Damit wird das ganze wortwörtlich zur *fringe theory*. sigh